# folder path with space giving error in subprocess.call

Tags: python-3.x

```
    drivesToMap = ["R: \\\\server1\folder", "G: \\\\server1\folder withSpace"]
    for eachDrive in drivesToMap:
        call("net use " + eachDrive)
```

In python 3 on a windows 10 machine I am getting the following error for the code above :

System error 1232 has occurred.

The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.

How do I resolve the space?  When I type in the command from a doc cmd it works succussfully:

net use G: \server1\folder withSpace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to wrap the drive in an additional set of quotes, since `net use` is a command prompt command it is anticipating that the drive name (which has spaces) is actually multiple arguments instead of one.

For instance:

```
drivesToMap = ["'R: \\\\server1\folder'", "'G: \\\\server1\folder withSpace'"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  Gives me syntax error for net use.  So, I tried  drivesToMap = ["' R: '\\\\server1\folder' ", "G: '\\\\server1\folder withSpace' "] which gives original problem

Comment: Might try escape double quotes instead

Comment: Thank you.  The escape double quotes worked.  The catch was it had to be for the file path and not around the drive letter as such: drivesToMap = ["R: \"\\\\server1\folder\" ", "G: \"\\\\server1\folder withSpace\" "].  Thank you for the prompt response.